# Looping through nested yaml data in .erb file

Tags: yaml, frontend, erb, middleman

I'm not overly familiar with YAML syntax and can't seem to find a solution through search.

I'm trying to loop through this data file:

```
- category1:
  title: Title 1
  sub:
    name: name1
    desc: desc1
  sub:
    name: name2
    desc: desc2
  sub:
    name: name3
    desc: desc3
- category2:
  title: Title 2
  sub:
    name: name1
    desc: desc1
  sub:
    name: name2
    desc: desc2
  sub:
    name: name3
    desc: desc3
```

Here's my erb loop:

```
<% data.filename.category.each do |filter| %>
  <%= filter["title"] %>
  <% filter["sub"].each do |sub| %>
      <%= sub["name"] %>
      <%= sub["desc"] %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The desired result being:

Tile1

name1
desc1
name2
desc2
name3
desc3

Tile2

name1
desc1
name2
desc2
name3
desc3

Comment: I am not familiar with ERB but two things are obviously wrong: 1) `category 1` is at same indentation level as the following keys, making them siblings of the `category 1` key while I suppose they should be a nested mapping. 2) `data.filename.category` is unlikely to match anything since there is no `category` key in the YAML and the root object of the YAML is a sequence.

Comment: Also, in a YAML mapping, you cannot have multiple identical keys which you do with `sub`. You have to make the value of `sub` a sequence instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [How to get YAML files to render in middleman with erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635968/how-to-get-yaml-files-to-render-in-middleman-with-erb/46652372#46652372)...

The following should get you sorted out, it's mostly a question of data structure - your loop is on the right track:

Change the contents of `filename.yml` file to:

```
items:
- title:  "Title 1"
  subs:
    - name: "name1"
      desc: "desc1"
    - name: "name2"
      desc: "desc2"
    - name: "name3"
      desc: "desc3"
- title:  "Title 2"
  subs:
    - name: "name1"
      desc: "desc1"
    - name: "name2"
      desc: "desc2"
    - name: "name3"
      desc: "desc3"
```

And in your template file (assuming your data file is located at /data/filename.yml):

```
<% data.filename.items.each do |item| %>
    <h1><%= item.title %></h1>
    <% item.subs.each do |sub| %>
        <h2><%= sub.name %></h2>
        <h3><%= sub.desc %></h3>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```